# C# Console application calling a Web MVC DLL that reads Web.config fails to load Web.config values

Tags: c#, web-config

I have a console application that references an C# MVC web project DLL. The console application calls into some of the functions exposed in the controller. The controller then goes onto call other model functions.

Since the controller reads setting from its Web.config file (located in its project), when the console application calls into the controller functions, the settings that the controller reads is all null.

Is there a way around this other than my overriding all the controller APIs to also take in these settings as a parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Options you can think of:
1. Have the same settings in your App.config
2. Moving the settings in Web.config to resource file.